# Сравнение числа

Tags: php

Переменная num1 больше чем x, тогда почему не срабатывает условие

return 'Задуманное число не входит в числовой ряд' . '
';?

а если убрать цикл, то почему-то работает

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);

$x = 9;
$num1 = 10;
$num2 = 20;


echo '<br>';

function checking(){
    global $x;
    global $num1;
    global $num2;

    $x_int = (int) $x;

    while($num1 <= $x_int){
        echo 'Число ' .$x_int. '<br>';
        echo $num1 . '<br>';
        echo $num2 . '<br>';
        echo '<br>';

        if($num1 > $x_int){
            return 'Задуманное число не входит в числовой ряд' . '<br>';
        }

        else{
            if($num1 === $x_int){
                return 'Задуманное число входит в числовой ряд' . '<br>';
            }
            elseif($num1 !== $x_int){
                $num2 = $num1;
                $x_int = $x_int + $num1;
                $num1 = $num2;
            }
        }
    }   
}

echo checking();
```

[image: Блок схема]

Comment: Во первых не делайте так global $variable, а делайте так checking(variable);

Comment: ну и как я тогда потом буду изменять все значения переменных за функцией?

Comment: А зачем их изменять? Вы задание опишите и по какому условию итерирует цикл в блок схеме этого не видно, а в вашем коде условие не попадает изначально?

Comment: так не работает

Comment: http://pastebin.com/YHtA74F1

Answer (score 2):

У вас условие в цикле while говорит что цикл будет работать пока `$num1 <= $x_int`, а так как:

```
$x = 9;
$num1 = 10;
```

То получается что цикл не отрабатывает, так как 10 не может быть меньше или равно 9, поменяйте условие `$x_int <= $num1` и тогда увидите результат.

Comment: Я изменил, теперь если изменить значение x на 11, то ничего не будет выводится

Comment: Если Вам нужно любое условие то зачем вообще цикл в функции? Он там не нужен как по мне

Comment: почему цикл while не правильно работает? http://pastebin.com/YHtA74F1

Comment: Он работает правильно, но у вас в блок схеме указано что пользователь может ввести любые значения, и в данном случае он лишний.